# Can we integrate a WordPress blog in to an Angular JS website?

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

A friend of mine, a nutritionist, had her site designed by a company who has said that integrating WordPress into an angular js site is not possible. I haven't worked with angular but with jquery and Java and HTML. I don't see how that's true.  It's ultimately an HTML website.

Can the experts here verify this information?

Comment: Depends on how you want to integrate. You can create a subfolder for the blog and configure WordPress in it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Yes you can create blog folder on the root of angular.js website and named it blog and it inside it install the wordpress and run it.